# Cannot communicate once bufferedwriter is close in java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I made a server and client Java application.
They should communicate each other through TCP sockets with Threads.
I used InputStreamReader and BufferedReader to read message,
and I used OutputStreamWriter and BufferedWriter to write message.
The object of BufferedReader is called reader, and the object of BufferedWriter is called writer.

After playing around with that, I realized the socket becomes irresponsive if the writer is closed.

I closed the writer on server side because it will never send any message, but will read message from client only. it does not throw any exception, but stuck where I called any methods relate to socket such as reader.readline() and socket.setSoTimeout().

The problem was easy to solve since I just don't close the writer. However, I am very curious why the socket is being unable to communicate.

Comment: Closing the writer also closes the socket. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the socket becomes irresponsive if the writer is closed

The socket becomes *closed* if the writer is closed.

> I closed the writer on server side because it will never send any message,

*Non sequitur.* If you don't need the `Writer`, don't construct it.

> stuck where I called any methods relate to socket such as `reader.readline()` and `socket.setSoTimeout()`.

It isn't 'stuck'. It's closed. You must have got `SocketException: socket closed` when you called either of those methods. You should have noticed that, and you should have posted it in your question.

Comment: Thank you for simple explanation. The writer was created for testing(playing) purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can make stop it from being irresponsive by trying:

```
if(reader.ready()){
String result = reader.readline();
}
```

Comment: Not if it's closed, and `ready()` will return true if there is one byte available, not necessarily an entire line, so this kind of code will still block. It isn't useful.